# Octopus Deploy - Use index to select object from an aray

Tags: octopus-deploy

I've created a variable Named `ProcessingScript` with the following value

```
#{each SiteKey in BatchProcessing.SiteKeys}
ftp://#{BatchProcessing.FtpUser[#{Octopus.Template.Each.Index}]}@
{/each}
```

The idea is I iterate through my array `SiteKeys`  which look like this `SiteKeys ['customer1-a' customer1-b']`
and my FtpUsers which look like this `['usera', 'userb']`

However when i preview the variable it prints

```
#{BatchProcessing.FtpUser[#{Octopus.Template.Each.Index}]}customer1-a 
#{BatchProcessing.FtpUser[#{Octopus.Template.Each.Index}]}customer1-b
```

It completely ignoring the index

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reference list variables by index.

You can try these variables:

```
BatchProcessing.SiteKeys = "customer1-a,customer1-b"
BatchProcessing.FtpUser[customer-a] = "usera"
BatchProcessing.FtpUser[customer-b] = "userb"
```

And this template:

```
#{each SiteKey in BatchProcessing.SiteKeys}
ftp://#{BatchProcessing.FtpUser[#{SiteKey}]}@#{SiteKey}
{/each}
```

I think you can also get rid of the SiteKeys variable if you only use it for looping.

```
BatchProcessing[customer-a].FtpUser = "usera"
BatchProcessing[customer-b].FtpUser = "userb"
```

```
#{each site in BatchProcessing}
ftp://#{site.FtpUser}@#{site}
{/each}
```